# centroid algorithm robust to missing poins

Tags: graph-theory, coordinate-systems, estimation, centroid

I need to find a center point of a person given the coordinates of all the joints.

The joints of a person can be represented as a nodes of a graph with a fixed structure. The catch is some of the joints might be missing.

Is there a way to estimate the center point that won't change munch when one(or more) of the joints is not detected

[example of joints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EshX6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to detect your joints? If you detect your joints, you will get 18 coordinates for each person. If there is missing joint, you can recover using some matrix completion methods for missing joints.